# Whole regexp string as variable

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

```
my $re = 's/foo/bar/g';
my $x = 'one two foo';

$x =~ $re;
```

How to do this?

```
my $re1 = 'foo';
my $re2 = 'bar';

my $x = 'one two foo';

$x =~ s/$re1/$re2/g;
```

...is not a solution for me! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use substitution inside anonymous function,

```
my $re = sub { s/foo/bar/g for @_ };

my $x = 'one two foo';
$re->($x);
```

Comment: Slick way to avoid `eval`

Comment: @Zaid yes, but eval might be what OP wants if he reads regex from external source.

Comment: In your example `s/foo/bar/g` is constant but I need it as variable because it should be generated dynamically.

Comment: @Toru alternative is `my $re = eval "sub { $regex for \@_ }";`

Comment: @Сухой27 Very good, thanks. How to use an array regex (@regexes) instead of a scalar regex ($regex) to iterate over all regexes?

Comment: @Toru `$_->($x) for @Are;` when `@Are` is array of funcs with substitution.

Comment: That is a beautifully compact answer... +1 :)